# shared_ptr instances managed by a singleton cache across DLL boundaries generates runtime error R6025

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I encounter a OOP conceptual limitation when implementing a singleton in C++11/14 which caches a set of `shared_ptr` instances created from a third party DLL (external constraint with a poor design).

```cpp
//DLL1 data source session (third library)
class SessionFactory final
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<ISession> CreateSession(const std::string& pi_dataSourceId);
};
```

```cpp
//DLL2 client
class SessionCache final
{
public:
    static SessionCache& Get()
    {
        static SessionCache s_instance;
        return s_instance;
    }

    void clean() {m_sessions.clear();}

    std::shared_ptr<ISession> getSession(const std::string& pi_dataSourceId)
    {
        auto im = m_sessions.find(pi_dataSourceId);
        if (im == m_sessions.end())
        {
             auto l_session = SessionFactory::CreateSession(pi_dataSourceId);
             m_sessions.insert(pi_dataSourceId, l_session)
             return l_session;
        }
        else return im->second;
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ISession>> m_sessions;
};

//optional explicit singleton content cleaning
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason) 
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            SessionCache::Get().clean(); //=> runtime error R6025 pure virtual function call (cached ISession are no more referenced and their virtual dtor are called leading to runtime error R6025)
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

When I want to clean the cache when the client DLL is unloaded (explicitly from `DllMain` procedure or implicitly by the static instance destructor called), unfortunately I suffer a "runtime error R6025 pure virtual function call" system exception because DLL1 has already been unloaded when DLL2 is unloading.

As `ISession`'s destructor implementation belongs to DLL1, it is no more reachable at this step.

A tactical workaround has been to adapt the "static" singletion allocation with a dynamic allocation but the cached `ISession` destructors are no more called.

1. Does anybody know how I could elegantly address this technical problem?
2. Did anybody encounter this similar technical limitation under Unix like systems?

Comment: This problem had been solved by COM almost 3 decades ago. COM servers can implement [`DllCanUnloadNow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllcanunloadnow) that addresses exactly this issue, namely that a COM object knows when the module containing its implementation can be unloaded.

Comment: I totally agree COM (Component Object Model) answers this problem. Unfortunately, in this context, the third library on which we rely has not been modelized/implemented as a COM component. As a third library, we can't amend it. It has to be seen as an external technical constraint.

Comment: The fact that your functionality is implemented behind a (presumably) flat C-style API does not limit you in exposing that functionality using COM. The solution to your problem is to implement a COM server (that internally consumes an arbitrary set of 3rd party library). That's your only hope for a reliable solution. You cannot expect to pass a `std::shared_ptr` across module boundaries and hope that things work out (they [won't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unfortunately I suffer a "runtime error R6025 pure virtual function call" system exception because DLL1 has already been unloaded when DLL2 is unloading.

Then you need to ensure that DLL1 can't be unloaded until DLL2 is done using it.  Either by making DLL1 be a static dependency of DLL2, or by having DLL2 manually increment/decrement DLL1's reference count at runtime via `LoadLibrary()`/`FreeLibrary()`:

> The system maintains a per-process reference count on all loaded modules. **Calling LoadLibrary increments the reference count. Calling the FreeLibrary or FreeLibraryAndExitThread function decrements the reference count.** The system unloads a module when its reference count reaches zero or when the process terminates (regardless of the reference count).

```
//DLL2 client
HMODULE hDLL1 = NULL;

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason) 
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            hDLL1 = LoadLibrary(TEXT("dll1"));
            if (!hDLL1) return FALSE;
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            SessionCache::Get().clean();
            FreeLibrary(hDLL1);
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Or:

```
//DLL2 client
class SessionCache final
{
public:
    SessionCache()
    {
        hDLL1 = LoadLibrary(TEXT("dll1"));
        if (!hDLL1) throw ...;
    }

    ~SessionCache()
    {
        FreeLibrary(hDLL1);
    }

    ...

private:
    HMODULE hDll1;
    ...
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still having the issue despite this technical workaround. Maybe the problem I'm facing has other causes. I need to investigate.